# get bottom of screen position

Tags: jquery, mobile, responsive-design

I want to use jQuery or some other framework to get the bottom of the screen so when a smart banner shows up on the mobile application it modifies the screen to fit to the bottom, regardless of the banner.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: what do you mean by "bottom of the screen position"? are you looking for the height of the screen?

Comment: kind of, the issue I'm running into is I'm not able to make the screen be whatever is visible only, and not push the bottom down when a smart banner shows up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you are willing to have container height as much the viewport. Let's do this by an example. Assume that you have a main div `container` which surrounds everything else, a `p` tag to show the current size of `container` for display purpose, and an `button` to show and hide `banner`:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    Screen size is <p></p>
    <button type="button">push to add banner</button>
</div>
```

To change the height of `container` according to the height of window, we can do this in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  heightResize($(".container"));

  $(window).resize(function() {
    heightResize($(".container"));
  });
});

function heightResize(element) {
  element.height($(window).height()-20);
  $("p").text(element.height());
}
```

Then, the code to show/hide the banner and to change the height of `container` accordingly:

```
$("button").click(function() {

  if ($(".container").find(".banner").length != 0) {
     $(".container").find(".banner").remove();
     heightResize($(".container"));
  } else {
     $(".container").append("<div class='banner'>this is your dynamically created banner</div>");
     $(".container").height($(".container").height()+$(".banner").height());
  }

});
```

When `banner` is added dynamically, height of `container` will grow more than height of `window` for as much as the height of `banner`.

Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/bExyYV)